# Flask Routing filepath issues

Tags: routes, flask, converters

Why am I getting this odd problem with Flask routing

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html",
        title = 'Home',
        user = user,
        posts = posts)`
```

Works as expected

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html",
        title = 'Home',
        user = user,
        posts = posts)`
```

note the trailing slash works not as I expect. When I look at the terminal output Instead of 
"GET /static/images/foo.jpg"

I see
"GET /index/static/images/foo.jpg"

This really messes up when I am trying to do

```
@app.route('/index/<path:'page'>')
```

Is this the expected behaviour?
For some reason Miguel's microblog does this on my system also.

Comment: if static files are served by flask, i think it should be `"GET /static/images/foo.jpg"`, then the problem would be solved

Comment: Are you using `url_for` to get the URL for your static files or are you placing the URL directly in the template? If the latter, does it begin with a `/`?

Comment: I do return render_template('index.html',
        title = title,
        but = but,
        butb = butb).  In my other decorators it does the same thing, prepending a file directory.